# Moving object performance - ThreeJs

Tags: javascript, three.js

**Context :**

I'm working on a pretty simple THREE.JS project, and it is, I believe, optimized in a pretty good way.
I'm using a WebGLRenderer to display lot's of Bode plot extracted from an audio signal every 50ms. This is pretty cool, but obviously, the more Bode I display, the more laggy it is. In addition, Bodes are moving at constant speed, letting new ones some space to be displayed.

I'm now at a point where I implemented every "basic" optimization I found on Internet, and I managed to get a 30 fps constantly at about 10.000.000 lines displayed, with such a bad computer (nVidia GT 210 and Core i3 2100...).

Note also i'm `not using any lights`,reflections... Only basic lines =)

As it is a working project, i'm not allowed to show some screenshots/code, sorry ...

**Current implementation :**

I'm using an array to store all my Bodes, which are each displayed via a THREE.Line.
FYI, actually 2000 THREE.Line are used.

When a Bode has been displayed and moved for 40s, it is then deleted and the THREE.Line is re-used with another one. Note that to move these, I'm `modifying THREE.Line.position property`.

Note also that I already disabled my scene and object matrix autoUpdate, as I'm doing it manually. (Thx for pointing that Volune).

**My Question :**

> Do the THREE.Line.position modification induces some heavy
>   calculations the renderer has already done ? Or is three.js aware that my object did not change and
>   avoid these ?

In other words, I'd like to know if rendering/updating the same object which was just translated is heavier in the rendering process than just leaving it alone, without updating his matrix etc...
Is there any sort of low-level optimization, either in ThreeJS about rendering the same objects many times ? Is this optimization cancelled when I move my object ?

If so, I've in mind an other way to do this : using only two big Mesh, which are folowing each other, but this induces merging/deleting parts of their geometries each frames... Might it be better ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I found in the sources ([here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/1769fbfc6c994b51a54c15a5c096855fd3cb8a1a/src/renderers/WebGLRenderer.js#L3260) and [here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/1769fbfc6c994b51a54c15a5c096855fd3cb8a1a/src/core/Object3D.js#L504)) that the meshes matrices are updated each frame no matter the position changed or not.

This means that the **position modification does not induce heavy calculation itself**. This also means that a lot of matrices are updated and a lot of uniforms are sent to the GC each frame.

I would suggest trying your idea with one or two big meshes. This should reduce javascript computations internal to THREE.js, and the only big communications with the GC will be relative to the big buffers.
Also note that there exists a WebGL function `bufferSubData` ([MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn434079(v=vs.85).aspx)) to update parts of a buffer, but it seems [not yet usable in THREE.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/5042)

Comment: Thx for this answer, I did not even know bufferSubData, pretty interesting =) Actually, about the autoUpdates you pointed, I saw it few days ago, and tried disabling it and manually updating, which was a 20% fps upgrade. This said, I realize I was unclear about how deep in the rendering process my question was related. I'd like to know if rendering/updating the same object which was just translated is much heavier than just leaving it alone, without updating his matrix etc... BTW great post, giving rep and editing my post.

Comment: Forgot to say that I'm currently trying the 2 big meshes, will report results when done =)

Comment: As far as I know, updating a mesh is only necessary if any of the transforms changed. So the transform matrix can be recalculated. To save that step, instead of setting the transform, you could set the matrix directly. Not sure if that makes a difference tho. Correct me if im wrong